# sql connection are not

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

```java
 try {
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:C://127.0.0.1:1234//nizardb");
           
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
```

the output is:-
No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlite:C://127.0.0.1:1234//nizardb

Comment: What if you remove `C://`?

Comment: Do you actually have the SQLite JDBC driver on the classpath? Why do you think `C://127.0.0.1:1234//nizardb` is a valid path to a database file? It looks like a combination of a TCP/IP address and a Windows filepath, while SQLite only works with (valid) filepaths.

Comment: @JoopEggen That is unlikely to work, because SQLite requires a filepath and doesn't support - AFAIK - TCP/IP connections. However, the path used doesn't look valid.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver());
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
Connection conn= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:C://127.0.0.1:1234//nizardb");
```

You also need the JDBC driver.

Comment: Why would loading the Microsoft SQL Server JDBC driver help with connecting to a sqlite database? Also, user code should not call `DriverManager.registerDriver` (that is only to be called by JDBC drivers registering themselves) and using `Class.forName` to load a JDBC driver in a simple Java application hasn't been necessary since 2006.